# Cannot inject foreign repository into my controller

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

I've got a problem concerning a plugin I'm writing for Typo3. I want to have access to a repository (and the content of that) of a plugin in a different plugin. Like importing the stuff from one plugin to another. What I tried was using @inject in my controller, but the result is null.

```
    /**
     * @var \Sebkln\Ajaxselectlist\Domain\Repository\OptionRecordRepository
     */
    protected $optionRecordRepository = null;

    /**
     * @param \Sebkln\Ajaxselectlist\Domain\Repository\OptionRecordRepository
     */
    public function injectOptionRecordRepository(\Sebkln\Ajaxselectlist\Domain\Repository\OptionRecordRepository $optionRecordRepository) {
        $this->optionRecordRepository = $optionRecordRepository;
    }
```

And my action function:

```
$standorts = $this->optionRecordRepository->findAll();
$this->view->assign('standorts', $standorts);
```

My Typo3 version is 9.5, so may one got an idea what I should do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure, but I'm remembering something with dependencies... Does your extension require the other one or does declare the dependency (via ext_emconf.php/composer.json)? Otherwise, it can IMO lead to wrong loading orders.

Comment: @Julian no it dosent depend on some other ext but for progress I need records of a different plugin in my own plugin.. I can have a look into the json file. thx for advice and I come back with results :)

Comment: Ah, ok, misunderstood this.
Have you cleared your cache after editing these basics of your controller? (Admin -> Maintenance -> "Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the storagePid where the records are stored.

```
plugin.tx_[lowercasedextensionname] {
  persistence {
    storagePid = 12,22
  }
}
```

Or ignore it in repository if records are stored at unknown places.

```
/**
  * Initializes the repository.
  */
public function initializeObject()
{
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QuerySettingsInterface $querySettings */
    $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get(QuerySettingsInterface::class);
    $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
    $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
}
```

Comment: Ok sounds like something I can try. Thanks and I share the results after trying

Comment: Such a simple solution but didn't thought about that. Thanks!!